# How to use state in react native

Tags: react-native

[image]

[image]

Please refer to the images below. In the first image, I am creating an array of objects, and I am exporting it. and in the next image. I'm importing the array object. and I want to use the states. like setState() to this array object. I want to delete the item in this array object using the setState(). How should I do it?
I am new to this React Native programming. Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider watching any `React` tutorials? Learn the fundamentals first, watch few video tutorials.

Comment: i did watched those, there he used const [state, setState] = useState();

Comment: But I import the array object and I want to update it. how should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

```
import places from “../components/places”;

const PlacesScreen = (props) => {

    const [placesList, setPlaces] = useState(places); 

    function delete(index) {

      const data = […placesList];  
      data.splice(index, 1);
      setPlaces(data);
    }

    function renderItem({ item, index }) { 
  
      return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => delete(index)}>
            <Text>{item.Address}</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight> 
      );
    } 

    return (
         <FlatList 
           data={placesList} 
           renderItem={renderItem}
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />   
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Try this data.splice(i, 1);

Comment: i is my item or id?

Comment: " i " is the index of the item which is gonna be remove